# OpenGL es 2.0 and 16 bit channel

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

It possible to return 16 bit value from fragment shader on Android devices? 
I've made this conversion to convert 16 bit "x" value to 4444:

```
vec4 convertToVec4(float x)
{
    int iX = int(65535.0 * x);
    int r = (iX / (0x1000));
    int g = (iX / (0x100)) - r*0x10;
    int b = (iX / (0x10)) - (r*0x100 + g*0x10);
    int a = (iX) - (r*0x1000 + g*0x100 + b*0x10);
    return vec4(float(r)/15.0, float(g)/15.0, float(b)/15.0, float(a)/15.0);
}
```

and to get back 16 bit "x" from 4444:

```
float getFloat(vec4 v)
{
    vec4 col = v * 15.0;
    int sum = int(col.r*4096.0) + int(col.g*256.0) + int(col.b*16.0) + int(col.a);
    return float(sum) / 65535.0;
}
```

It works fine but it is very slow. Is there some way to pass 16 bit color in one channel (eg. red or alpha)?

Answer (score 0):

Two functions are in Shader ? If so you had better calculate that in cpu with neon  and then gives the returned value to GLSL

Why don't you use 32 bit channel instead of 16 bit ?